# converting as factor for a list of data frames

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I am trying to create a custom function to give labels to modified list of data frames. For example, I have a data frame like below.

```
df<-data.frame(
  gender = c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,2),
  country = c(3,3,1,2,5,4,4,4,4,3,3,4,3,4,2,1,4,2,3,4,4,4,3,1,2,1,5,5,4,3,1,4,5,2,3,4,5,1,4),
  Q1=c(1,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,1,1,1,NA,1,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,1),
  Q2=c(1,1,1,1,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,1,1,1,1,NA,NA,NA,1,1,1,NA,1,1,1,1,1,NA,NA,NA,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,NA,NA,NA),
  Q3=c(1,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,1,1,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,1,1,1,1,1,NA,NA,1),
  Q4=c(1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
  Q5=c(1,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,NA,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,NA,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,NA,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2)
)
```

Comment: I'm confused - is the goal to (a) copy the columns with new names (as in your `funct` pseudocode), (b) to copy the columns with new names *and* convert them to `factor` class (implied by *"a list of variables for labeling as factor"*), or (c) to copy the columns with new names *and* convert them to factors *and* give the factors specific labels (as in your *"#Labelling is done for categorical variables"* chunk, or (d) something else?

Comment: b) what ever the labelled in Q1 , create a new column Q1_new and labelled the same as done in Q1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand your goal to be the following: You want to take a list of data frames (ldat). For each of the dataframes in the list (df, df2) you want to take some existing columns (Q1, Q2, Q3) and replicate them with new names in the same data frame (Q1_new, Q2_new, Q3_new). This you could achieve like this:

```
variables = c("Q1","Q2","Q3")
new_label =c("Q1_new","Q2_new","Q3_new")

newdfs <- lapply(ldat, FUN = function(x) {
  x[,new_label] = x[,variables]
  return(x)})
```

```
head(newdfs$ALL)

  gender country   Q1        Q2      Q3               Q4       Q5 cc2 Q1_new    Q2_new  Q3_new
1   Male     USA  Yes Available Partner Depends on sales    Local   1    Yes Available Partner
2 female     USA  Yes Available Partner             <NA> Overseas  NA    Yes Available Partner
3   Male     CAN <NA> Available    <NA>             <NA>    Local   1   <NA> Available    <NA>
4 female      EU <NA> Available    <NA>             <NA>    Local   1   <NA> Available    <NA>
5   Male      UK <NA> Available    <NA>             <NA>    Local   1   <NA> Available    <NA>
6 female      BR <NA>      <NA>    <NA>             <NA> Overseas  NA   <NA>      <NA>    <NA>
```

Is this what you had in mind?